# Filter the tree response Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a `Person` class and an endpoint that generates the response in a tree, and it works. Now I need to add a filter with a list of `id` to create a response in this tree with the parents associated to the `id` of that list, below I show the response without filter and the expected response with the filter. How could I implement this filter?

**Unfiltered response:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fullName": "William",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "fullName": "Henry",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "fullName": "Matt",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 7,
                                "fullName": "Sophi",
                                "children": [],
                                "rootParentId": 1
                            }
                        ],
                        "rootParentId": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "fullName": "Alisa",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 6,
                                "fullName": "Alexa",
                                "children": [],
                                "rootParentId": 1
                            }
                        ],
                        "rootParentId": 1
                    }
                ],
                "rootParentId": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "fullName": "May",
                "children": [],
                "rootParentId": 1
            }
        ],
        "rootParentId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "fullName": "Olivia",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "fullName": "John",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "fullName": "Oliver",
                        "children": [],
                        "rootParentId": 8
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "fullName": "Mia",
                        "children": [],
                        "rootParentId": 8
                    }
                ],
                "rootParentId": 8
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "fullName": "Mary",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 13,
                        "fullName": "Evelyn",
                        "children": [],
                        "rootParentId": 8
                    }
                ],
                "rootParentId": 8
            }
        ],
        "rootParentId": 8
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "fullName": "Eric",
        "children": [],
        "rootParentId": null
    }
]
```

**filterList** = [ 7, 12 ]

**Expected response with filter:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fullName": "William",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "fullName": "Henry",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "fullName": "Matt",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 7,
                                "fullName": "Sophi",
                                "children": [],
                                "rootParentId": 1
                            }
                        ],
                        "rootParentId": 1
                    }                    
                ],
                "rootParentId": 1
            }
        ],
        "rootParentId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "fullName": "Olivia",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "fullName": "John",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "fullName": "Mia",
                        "children": [],
                        "rootParentId": 8
                    }
                ],
                "rootParentId": 8
            }
        ],
        "rootParentId": 8
    }
]
```

**My Classes**

**Model**

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernate_lazy_initializer", "handler"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String fullName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonIgnore
    private Person parent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonIgnore
    private Person rootParent;

    @Transient
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public List<Person> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getRootParentId() {
        if (parent != null) {
            return parent.getRootParentId();
        } else if (children != null && !children.isEmpty()) {
            return id;
        } else return null;
    }

}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p "
            + " WHERE p.parent.id IS NULL")
    List<Person> findRoots();

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p"
            + " WHERE p.rootParent.id IN :rootIds ")
    List<Person> findChildrenInRoots(@Param("rootIds") List<Long> rootIds);

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/person")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepo personRepo;
    
    @GetMapping("/tree")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Person> getChildren() {
        List<Person> rootCategories = personRepo.findRoots();

        List<Long> rootCategoryIds = rootCategories.stream().map(Person::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Person> children = personRepo.findChildrenInRoots(rootCategoryIds);

        children.forEach(subCategory -> {
            subCategory.getParent().getChildren().add(subCategory);
        });

        return rootCategories;
    }
}
```

**Data**

```
insert into PERSON values (1,'William',null, null);
insert into PERSON values (2,'Henry',1,1);
insert into PERSON values (3,'Matt',2,1);
insert into PERSON values (4,'Alisa',2,1);
insert into PERSON values (5,'May',1,1);
insert into PERSON values (6,'Alexa',4,1);
insert into PERSON values (7,'Sophi',3,1);
insert into PERSON values (8,'Olivia',null,null);
insert into PERSON values (9,'John',8,8);
insert into PERSON values (10,'Mary',8,8);
insert into PERSON values (11,'Oliver',9,8);
insert into PERSON values (12,'Mia',9,8);
insert into PERSON values (13,'Evelyn',10,8);
insert into PERSON values (14,'Eric',null,null);
```

Thank's for your help!

Comment: Where are you stuck doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would love to use [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) and filter for something like `$[?(@..id in [7,12])]`, yet this returns too much data. First of all, I would separate the entity from the dto/response, just to be sure to be able to manipulate the objects without changing the data persisted. Then it becomes just a tree traversal: a silly solution is

```
private static Person filter(Person person, Set<Long> ids) {
    if (person == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (shouldDiscard(person, ids)) {
        return null;
    }
    person.setChildren(
        person.getChildren().stream()
        .map(child -> filter(child, ids))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return shouldDiscard(person, ids) ? null : person;
}

private static boolean shouldDiscard(Person person, Set<Long> ids) {
    return isEmpty(person.getChildren()) && !ids.contains(person.getId());
}

private static boolean isEmpty(Collection<?> collection) {
    return collection == null || collection.stream().allMatch(Objects::isNull);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I will use this approach, in my use case I am separating the entity from the dto/response. Thank you very much for your help!